# Couldn't find Student with 'student_id'= RUBY ON RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to pull up an edit page for my simple system.

Here's my controller for student look like:

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @students = Student.newest_first
  end

  def show
    @student = Student.find(params[:student_id])
  end

  def new
    @student = Student.new
  end

  def create
    @student = Student.new(student_params_create)
    if @student.save
    flash[:notice] = "Student record created successfully"
    redirect_to(students_path)
    else
    render('new')
    end
  end

  def edit
    @student = Student.find(params[:student_id])
  end

  def update
    @student = Student.find(params[:student_id])
    if @student.update_attributes(student_params_update)
    flash[:notice] = "Students updated"
    redirect_to(students_path)
  else
    render('edit')
  end
  end

  def delete
    @student = Student.find(params[:student_id])
  end

  def destroy
    @student = Student.find(params[:student_id])
    @student.destroy
  end

  private

  def student_params_create
    params.require(:student).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :birthday, :email, :subjects, :username, :password)
  end

  def student_params_update
    params.require(:student).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :birthday, :email, :subjects)
  end

end
```

And I am trying to here's my index page where I can click edit on my student.

```
<% @students.each do |student|%>
<%= student.first_name %>
<%= student.student_id %>

  <%= link_to("Show", student_path(student), :class => 'action show') %>
  <%= link_to("Edit", edit_student_path(student), :class => 'action edit') %>
  <%= link_to("Delete", delete_student_path(student), :class => 'action delete') %>
<% end %>
```

For my form edit, I got the ff:

```
  <h2>Update Subject</h2>
<%= form_for(@student) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field(:first_name) %>
<%= f.datetime_select(:created_at, :order => [:month, :day, :year]) %><
<%= f.submit("Update Subject") %>

<% end %>
```

When I tried to go to my resource for students: `http://localhost:3000/students/`

And click on one of my students I got the ff: error:

[image]

Any idea what am I doing wrong????

EDIT:

I set the 'id' to false during migration.

```
def up
    create_table :students, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer "student_id",:primary_key => true
      t.string "first_name", :limit => 25
      t.string "last_name", :limit => 50
      t.string "email", :default => ' ', :null => false
      t.string "birthday"
      t.string "subjects"
      t.string "teachers"
      t.string "username", :limit => 25
      t.string "password_digest"
      t.timestamps
    end
    reversible do |dir|
       dir.up { execute "ALTER TABLE students AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000" }
    end
    # execute "CREATE SEQUENCE students_student_id_seq OWNED BY students.student_id INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1001"
  end

  def down
  drop_table :students
  # execute "DELETE SEQUENCE students_student_id_seq"
  end
```

Routes:

```
  resources :students do
    member do
       get :delete
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

You could need to update your `routes.rb` with

```
resources :students, param: :student_id
```

And your `Student` model with

```
self.primary_key = :student_id
```

**NOTE** that you're having the `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception because `find` method throws exception when it can't actually find the record needed. Try to use `find_by_id` method instead. It will just return `nil` in that situation. You'll be able to handle it easily and your app will not crash here. So you could edit your `show` action like this

```
def show
  @student = Student.find_by_id(params[:student_id])
end
```

Comment: the 'id' was set to false, I am using my own custom id set via 'student_id', I do have a student with an id of '1000' and '1001'.. I am not sure why the trace is looking at 'id' where is it must be on  'student_id' where in fact i specify this  `@student = Student.find(params[:student_id])`

Comment: I did try that but still i am having the same error

Comment: `resources :students do
    member do
       get :delete
    end
  end`

Comment: That did the trick except for the 'find_by_id'. Can you explain in layman's term what really happened here? why do I need to put self.primary_key = :student_id on model and `resources :students, param: :student_id`. I want to understand what happened.

Comment: It's just how one do it in Rails. To change the primary key you have to create and execute correct migration, set primary key in the model and set param for the resource routes. `find_by_id` has nothing to do with primary keys. I just told you about that as a good practice - to return nil instead of raise exception. If my answer was helpful I'll appreciate if you accept it as corrct one.